# Eclipse Error:JDOMAbout$Author.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

Tags: java

I have imported the `rs2xml` jar file along with mysql connector files into reference libraries my project. I also have `javafx` into my module path.

I get this error when I try to run my main class:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for
C:\MScSoftware\mscProjectV6\src\jdbcConnector\rs2xml.jar Caused by:
java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException:
JDOMAbout$Author.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package
not allowed in module)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the file `r2xml.jar` in Module path to classpath.

Comment: Hi Mory, could you give us more detail on how to do it?

Comment: you figured it out ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your

> rs2xml.jar

file from module path to class path it will work.

Answer (score 0):

right click project -> build path -> configure build path
Instead of order and export, click libraries in the central panel , delete jar from module path and add to classpath.